# How to place Chat widget in all the pages in Liferay DXP?

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-theme, liferay-dxp

We are using Liferay DXP Portal for our customer facing website and we like to implement chat widget in all the pages.

If we click on chat widget then chat window is opening , this logic we have but we are stuck in implementing chat widget in all the pages to the right.

Eg, if customer navigates to any page in our site then he/she should see chat widget in the right side of the browser, I have attached screen for example.

[image]

How can I achieve this in Liferay DXP portal?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: Has this been cross-posted, @OlafKock? If so, would you supply a link in the comments or edited into the footer of the question?

Comment: I'm always hoping that the OP realizes that crossposting isn't nice and cross-link themselves (or delete one of the questions). Well, as OP hasn't shown up again, here it is: https://web.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/110021818

Comment: But you could also add an external chat, that depends on the use you want to give to the liferay's own chat ... Insert the code and solve the code in the Liferay piwik

Answer (score 0):

As Liferay also has their own chat on Marketplace, with the source code available, you can start there and look up its implementation: It's a portlet that gets added to all pages, and the [code is on github](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/chat/chat-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/chat/web/portlet/ChatPortlet.java#L63). Note that with any @Activate, there's a @Deactivate, and you'll find it a few lines down (implement both!).

Another option is to implement your theme to [statically and unconditionally include this portlet](https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/embedding-portlets-in-themes-and-layout-templates) on your page.

This is assuming that you've implemented your chat as a portlet, of course.